# Shopify "Add to Cart" not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I am working on a Shopify website for one of my clients. They requested a custom Live Preview option on their product page. This option includes a drop down menu that allows you to select a certain font, and below that, a text field to type in any numbers or letters, which then generate a live preview option to view the numbers or letters in the font selected. I added custom HTML, CSS & JS to get this to start working. All seems to work well but now the "Add to Cart" button on the product page shows "Unavailable".

Additionally, I noticed that when I was able to "Add to Cart", the cart doesn't show any of the custom preview options selected.

https://house-numbers1.myshopify.com/collections/flat-cut-metal/products/flat-cut-metal-17

```
var TextInput = document.getElementById('Line1');
var Fonts = document.getElementById('product-select-option-0');
var Preview = document.getElementById('Preview');

TextInput.addEventListener('keyup', textChange, false);

function textChange() {
  Preview.textContent = TextInput.value;
}

Fonts.addEventListener('change', fontChange, false);

function fontChange() {
  var newClass = this.value.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "").replace(/\s/g, '_');
  Preview.className = newClass;
  console.log(newClass);
};
```

```
<select class="single-option-selector" data-option="option1" id="product-select-option-0">
  <option value="AR Julian">AR Julian</option>
  <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
  <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Pacifico">Pacifico</option>
</select>
<div>
  <p><strong>Live Preview:</strong></p>
  <p>
    <input required="" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Type Here" id="Line1" name="properties[Line 1:]">
  </p>  
</div>
<div id="Preview">Text preview</div>
</br>
</br>
  {%- if section.settings.show_quantity_selector -%}
    <div class="form__control">
      <label class="form__label">{{ 'product.form.quantity' | t }}</label>
      <div class="quantity-selector" >
        <a href="#" data-action="decrease-product-quantity" title="{{ 'product.form.decrease_quantity' | t }}">{%- include 'icon' with 'minus' -%}</a>
        <span class="quantity-selector__current-quantity">1</span>
        <a href="#" data-action="increase-product-quantity" title="{{ 'product.form.increase_quantity' | t }}">{%- include 'icon' with 'plus' -%}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
  <div class="product__payment-container">
    {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available -%}
      <button type="submit" class="product__add-to-cart button button--primary">
        {%- if product.template_suffix == 'pre-order' -%}
          {{- 'product.form.pre_order' | t -}}
        {%- else -%}
          {{- 'product.form.add_to_cart' | t -}}
        {%- endif -%}
      </button>
    {%- else -%}
      <button type="submit" class="product__add-to-cart button button--secondary" disabled="disabled">{{ 'product.form.sold_out' | t }}</button>
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- if section.settings.show_payment_button -%}
      {{ form | payment_button }}
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
```

```
.Brush_Script {
  font-family: Brush Script;
}

.Freehand {
  font-family: Freehand;
}

.Old_English {
  font-family: Old English;
}

.AR_Julian {
  font-family: AR Julian;
}

.Impact {
  font-family: Impact;
}

.Times_New_Roman {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.Allura {
  font-family: Allura;
}
.Arial {
  font-family: Arial;
}
.OpenSans {
  font-family: Open Sans Light;
}
.Helvetica {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.Courier {
  font-family: Courier;
}
.Verdana {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.Pacifico {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}


#Preview {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#Preview {
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
}
```

Comment: Any errors at all in the browser developer tools console? with the code you've shown there's no indication how showing "Unavailable" can possibly occur, since that word doesn't appear in your code - the conclusion is, that the code that is causing this issue is something you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX I was able to fix the issue, but for some reason, when I "Add to Cart", the cart doesn't show any of the custom preview options selected(font name), I am not sure how to link this.